# How can I show angle braces < text > when using CSS in xaringan

Tags: css, r-markdown, xaringan

I would like to color different words in xaringan slides using CSS.

I made a file called stuff.css that contains this:

```
.red {
color: red;  
}
```

And my rmarkdown file has this:

```
---
title: "test"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["stuff.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
---

blah .red[<command]

blah .red[command>]

blah .red[<command>]
```

The first two lines display as I expect (with the text inside of the `[` `]` in red) but the third one only shows blah.  Why is this happening? How can I get the third line to display blah followed by the word command in angle braces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

This should do the trick. Add these to your `css` file:

```
.red {
  color: red;  
}

.red:before {
    content: '\003C';
}

.red:after {
    content: '\003E';
}
```

Then, just call `.red[command]`. The special characters `<` and `>` will be added before, with `red:before`, and after, with `red:after`, respectively.

Comment: That is some high quality magic.  Thank you!  Do you have any idea why text in angle braces < > goes not display by xaringan?

Comment: You're welcome. I guess it's related to HTML elements, which are called inside angle braces `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS multiple ways in Rmarkdown to control colored words in the output. The overall body color is `red`, while I can override the color with inline CSS code.

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
body{
  color: red;
}
```

red

<span style="color:black">black</span>

<span style="color:green">green</span>
````

[image]

Comment: That is a great idea for a workaround. Thank you.   Unfortunately <span style="color:red"><red></span> does not print. Apparently the problem is xaringan does not show anything inside angle braces.